# Can an algebraic structure such that $x+a=x+b$, have solutions for all $a,b∈\mathbb{K}$ exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, magma

Does there exist an algebraic structure $(\mathbb{K},+)$ such that equations of the form $x+a=x+b$, $a\neq b$ have solutions for all $a,b\in \mathbb{K}$?

Comment: Sure. For instance, take $K = \mathbb{Z}$, interpret $+$ as multiplication, and take $x = 0$.

Comment: Let $K$ be a non-empty set and fix an element $0\in K$. Then define $x+y=0$ for all $x,y\in K$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be any set. On $S$ we define $+$ the following way
$$x+y=x$$

Then $(S,+)$ is a semigroup which has your property. If $S$ is infinite, your equation has infinitelly many solutions.

I think you can also add an identity to this $(S,+)$ to make it into a monoid with the required property.

Comment: Yes you can add an identity: it won't be a solution $x$ for $x+a=x+b$ but this latter may still have solutions!

Comment: One way to make this construction more natural is, consider the set of all constant functions on $S$ and interpret $+$ as function composition. By adding identity function on $S$ into this collection, you can make a monoid.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out already in the first two comments to your question, yes, it exists.

Consider for example the finite magma with Cayley table:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3
\end{array}$$

over the set $K=\{0,1,2,3\}$.

This is a [right quasigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Right-_and_left-quasigroups) (the operation may be defined as $x+y:=x$ for all $x,y\in K$) and, here, we have

$$x+a=x+b\quad\forall x,a,b\in K.$$