# Abstract Algebra in analyzing computer science

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, computer-science

I would like to know of some uses of algebraic structures to study computer science. Parallels of what I am looking for would be stuff like the fundamental group/homology/cohomology in topology and class fields in number theory where groups/rings are used to represent information about the object we are studying. I am not asking for examples like the graph isomorphism problem. Is there any equivalent in computer science? I would very much appreciate references too.

Comment: [Crossposted to cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/37276/98).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Maurice Herlihy's work on applications of topology in distributed computing. He won a Turing award for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're interested in properly, but [this book](https://books.google.it/books?id=e9tQAAAAMAAJ&sa=X&ei=fE66VPr5M8fhaOn0gLAM) shows "applications" of abstract algebra, and a nice unusual example of finite semigroup (see [this later answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103223/does-a-non-abelian-semigroup-without-identity-exist/1118765#1118765)), in the context of computing machines.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract Algebra is commonly used to formalize the idea of combination and composition on a general level. There are many examples but I will discuss what I know here.

There are formalisms used to clarify what it means to combine types.

- In the category of "types" in category theory, where morphisms are computable functions, one can use the notions of product and coproduct (or sum type) to define binary operations.
- A semigroup is used to capture the idea of building types from others unrestrictedly since a semigroup has closure and associativity properties, a step better than category theory.
- From a semigroup, if one adds and identity, you get a monoid; if you add inverses to a monoid, you get a group. A group can formalize composition of invertible functions. From this intuition, groups can represent systems of lossless compression algorithms.
- Driving all categorial explorations in computer science is possibly the [Curry-Howard correspondence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence)