# A semigroup with three or four elements without identity

Tags: examples-counterexamples, semigroups

Does there exist a semigroup with three or four (or finite) elements, without identity?

I tried to construct such an example, but every example I tried to construct had an identity element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another example. With three elements take $aa=ab=ac=a$ and $ba=bb=bc=b$ and $ca=cb=cc=c$

Then any product e.g. $vwxyz$, however bracketed, is equal to the first element appearing in it i.e. $v$. So this is associative. But there is no identity.

This can be extended to provide an associative multiplication without identity on sets of various sizes.

Answer (score 5):

A semigroup is closed and associative under the operation (which we will call multiplication) but need have no other properties.

Consider a set $S$ with three elementsw $\{a,b,c\}$ with multiplication defined by
$$
\forall x,y \in S : xy = a$$
It is trivial to see that this is colsed, and easy to see that associativity holds (the second more than one element is involved, the answer becomes $a$ and stays that way).

Yet there is no identity. In particular, there is no element $e$ such that $eb=b$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ast & 1 & 2 & 3\\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
3 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
\end{array} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \begin{array}{c|cccc}
\bullet & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 4\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4\\
3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4\\
4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4\\
\end{array}$$
are two examples of finite, associative magmas with no identity element, of order $3$ and $4$ respectively.

Also: [Does a non-abelian semigroup without identity exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103223/does-a-non-abelian-semigroup-without-identity-exist/1118765#1118765)